# Missing CoTaskMemFree when building LLVM example on Windows

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm attempting to essentially follow the [llvm Kaleidoscope example](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html).

I'm on Windows. I built llvm from source per the directions on the site. It took quite a long time but it finally built successfully (no errors at least).

Then with my own code I am running this command:

```
$  clang-cl main.obj llvm/lib/LLVMCore.lib llvm/lib/LLVMSupport.lib /MDd -o build\test.exe
```

My `main.cpp` code has this in it:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"

std::unique_ptr<Module> module = llvm::make_unique<Module>("my cool jit", getGlobalContext());
```

And I'm not getting any parser errors but I am getting an error from the linker that for the life of me I cannot figure out:

```
LLVMSupport.lib(Path.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
__imp_CoTaskMemFree referenced in function "bool __cdecl 
llvm::sys::path::getKnownFolderPath(struct _GUID,class 
llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char> &)" (?
getKnownFolderPath@path@sys@llvm@@YA_NU_GUID@@AEAV?$SmallVectorImpl@D@3@@Z)

build\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Which library do I have to link to for this function to be defined? I can see the implementation in the code I built from. Do I need to build llvm in a particular way for this to be exported?

**EDIT:**

It turns out that I needed to read [the clang-cl documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) a little better where it says:

> To enable clang-cl to find system headers, libraries, and the linker when run from the command-line, it should be executed inside a Visual Studio Native Tools Command Prompt or a regular Command Prompt where the environment has been set up using e.g. vcvars32.bat.

It turns out that this solves my problem. I was a little confused because `clang-cl` seems to resolve the sdk include and tool paths automatically, but not the lib paths. I also don't want to use CMD to drive clang so I was using bash where I can't run `vcvar32.bat` easily. I solved my problem by essentially duplicating what `vcvar32.bat` is doing to the `$PATH`, `$INCLUDE`, `$LIB` and `$LIBPATH` environment variables and adding `Ole32.Lib` as a parameter to `clang-cl`. It then works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the CoTaskMemFree symbol. A quick look on the Internet suggests you'll need the Ole32 system library on your link line.

I don't have access to a Windows machine to test on, but on my computer, I can run `llvm-config --system-libs` and it pulls in the all the necessary things. After adding `using namespace llvm;` and adding a stub `main` function, I can easily build this example with (on OSX):

```
c++ `llvm-config --cxxflags` main.cpp `llvm-config --ldflags --system-libs --libs core support`
```

I often recommend just specifying `--libs` rather than guessing what you'll need, but your choice.

Comment: Yeah I totally missed that CoTaskMemFree is what is missing. Also, I have no idea why but llvm-config doesn't ship with clang on windows and there seems to be no where to download it. So I have been trying to not rely on it since I don't want to make other people do a 3 hour build just to get it. Also my franken-system appears to have too many visual studios installed and llvm-config seems to be unable to build correct paths. I'm doing a scorch earth uninstall then I will try to get minimal dependencies back on. Its very frustrating.

Comment: `llvm-config` is part of the LLVM source tree, it should build by default and end up in your "bin" directory wherever you built LLVM on your machine. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't build on Windows too. The source code for the tool is in `tools/llvm-config` in the LLVM checkout. You will need to update your `%PATH%` for it to be visible of course.

Comment: It does build on windows, but it would be really nice if it shipped with the clang installer since it seems like you can't really use clang without it and building llvm takes 3 hours on my machine.

Comment: So it turns out that I was a little confused because it seems like clang-cl is able to automatically add include paths to windows sdk but it doesn't also add sdk lib paths. It does however say on the clang-cl documentation page: `To enable clang-cl to find system headers, libraries, and the linker when run from the command-line, it should be executed inside a Visual Studio Native Tools Command Prompt or a regular Command Prompt where the environment has been set up using e.g. vcvars32.bat.` which would have totally solved my problem. I was hoping not to have to do this since I want to use bash

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but surely the VS command prompt is not magical? I expect it just sets up some environment variables automatically that you could replicate in bash?

Comment: I had the same thought, I ended up figuring it out and now it works from bash as well: https://github.com/justinmchase/node-clang-build/blob/master/lib/config-win32.js